# Saving Memory / Calling external code and dumping memory used before continuing

Tags: php, out-of-memory

I've got a backup script that continually builds excel files as it executes.  The main script calls a class to handle the excel file build a few hundred times (one for each excel file).

The problem is that with each cycle of the loop, calling on the class to build the next excel file just adds to the used memory. Eventually this overwhelms the memory allocated for the execution.

I know the temporary answer is increase the memory allowed, but I was hoping I could wrap the file building with some memory-type ob_start/ob_clean functions.

I've tried to debug with xdebug for the past couple of days and I don't see any gaping holes that would cause the problem -- the memory usage is a pretty gradual increase overtime.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try separating the actual "work" in a separate .php script and calling that using `shell_exec` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) from your main script.

That way any memory allocated by the "worker" script is automatically cleared when it finishes executing.

Also you might look at CRON jobs to execute the main script at intervals instead of allowing it to run as a daemon.

There's also [forking](https://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php).

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping there was something I didn't know about php that would help. I just didn't expect php to keep ahold of data it didn't need.

Side note: was this a poorly worded question, not sure why the downvote

Comment: PHP uses the garbage collector pattern. If you don't properly delete references to unused data then you'll see memory usage go up. There are also plenty of memory leaks in the interpretor itself and in most third party libraries so no matter how good you clean up after yourself memory consumption will always go up.